# Place long description under short description

Tags: magento2

How can I place the long description below the short description?
[image: place long description]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move `product.info.description` to `product.info.main`

Create `catalog_product_view.xml`

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="product.info.description" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.addto"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 2):

In our theme goto below file

> File Path : Magento_Catalog\layout\catalog_product_view.xml

add this line at bottom before body close.

```
<move element="product.info.description" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.overview" />
```

> product.info.description - description block name
>
> product.info.main - outer container name
>
> product.info.overview - short description block name

**Note :**

> File Path : Magento_Catalog\layout\catalog_product_view.xml

If this file is not there in our theme need to copy from vendor folder

then clean all head and body tag data and add above line (move tag).

clear cache and page refresh page you will get expected result.